# How to dynamicly add/modify ASP MenuItems?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Asp:Menu Control on MasterPage connected to a asp:SiteMapDataSource.

### Goal

Dynamicly add multiple submenu items to one of the menu items at start of the application.

#### Idea 1 - Custom SiteMapProvider

Seems like reinventing the wheel.

#### Idea 2 - Custom SiteMapResolveEventHandler

I tried the following, but it doesn't have any (visible) effect.

```
// In Site.Master.cs
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SiteMap.SiteMapResolve += new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(GenerateSubMenu);
}

private SiteMapNode GenerateSubMenu(Object sender, SitemapResolveEventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapNode currentNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode?.Clone(true);
    if (currentNode == null) return null;
    currentNode.Title = "TEST";
    return currentNode; // Displayed Menu doesn't change
}
```

#### Idea 3 - Modifying the MenuControl's Items Collection

I tried to modify the menuItems in the menu control events:
In the OnInit and OnLoad event the Items Collection is empty.

```
var menu = (Menu)sender;
if (menu.Items.Count < 4) return; // always is 0
var item = menu.Items[3];
```

Comment: What should the submenu item do? Provide a link to an aspx page? To some other page?

Comment: It should be a link to a aspx page with additional query string like status.aspx?i=0123. These values are stored in a config file and read at application start.

Comment: hm... why do you use .Clone()?

Comment: @Marcel This is how I found it in an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178425.aspx) that does something similar. But I also tried it without Clone(). Outcome is the same: Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to successfully implement idea 2.
Basically I add the dynamic nodes to the in-memory representation of the sitemap the first time the SiteMapResolveHandler gets called.

```
// Site.Master.cs
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SiteMap.SiteMapResolve += new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(GenerateSubMenu);
}

private static bool siteMapModified = false;

private SiteMapNode GenerateSubMenu(Object sender, SitemapResolveEventArgs e)
{
    if (!siteMapModified)
    {
        var rootChildNodes = SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes;
        if (rootChildNodes.Count > 3)
        {
            siteMapModified = true;
            var targetNode = rootChildNodes[3];
            targetNode.ReadOnly = false;

            // create writeable collection
            var childNodes = new SiteMapNodeCollection(targetNode.ChildNodes);

            var statusUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/status.aspx");

            var elements= LoadDynamicElements();
            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                childNodes.Add(
                    new SiteMapNode(
                        targetNode.Provider, 
                        element, 
                        statusUrl + "?k=" + element, 
                        element));
            }

            targetNode.ChildNodes = childNodes;
       }
   }

   return SiteMap.CurrentNode;
}
```